# Insert statement contains more than 1000 elements

Tags: java, sql, string, jdbc, set

I'm trying to add 100,000 names to a database using JDBC. I'm aware that MS SQL doesnt allow mass inserts of more than 1000, elmts, so I accomplish this by breaking the major set down into sets containing 1000 or fewer. The following is my code:

```
StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner("\'), (\'", "INSERT INTO Names (Name) VALUES (\'", "\');");
    ExecutorService threadpool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
    while(names.size() > 0) {

        int count = Math.min(1000, names.size());
        HashSet<String> set = new HashSet();
        Iterator iterator = names.iterator();
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
           set.add((String) iterator.next());
        }
        names.removeAll(set);
        for(String s: set)
        {
            joiner.add(s);
        }
       // System.out.println(joiner.toString());

        threadpool.submit(() -> {
            PreparedStatement query = null;
            try {
                query = connect.prepareStatement(joiner.toString());
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                query.executeUpdate();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

    }


}
```

This throws the following exception: `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The number of row value expressions in the INSERT statement exceeds the maximum allowed number of 1000 row values.`

Why are there more than 1000 lines being added?

Comment: debug you code... check the size of your set... place counters in loops and so on.

Comment: thats done the set is 1000

Comment: does the original query string already have 1 before 1000 get's added?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use batch inserts? Define batch size 1000 and insert queries in the batches of 1000 queries at a time.

```
String sql = "insert into names(name) values (?)";
Connection connection = new getConnection();
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

final int batchSize = 1000;
int count = 0;

for (Employee employee: employees) {

    ps.setString(1, employee.getName());
    ps.addBatch();

    if(++count % batchSize == 0) {
        ps.executeBatch();
    }
}
ps.executeBatch(); // insert remaining records
ps.close();
connection.close();
```

Comment: what does this do? : if(++count % batchSize == 0) {
        ps.executeBatch();
    }

Comment: it executes the batch when count is 1000, 2000, 3000, etc only. Not on every single count.